# two docker compose files that run two different application with the same images

Tags: docker

I have a question that is related more to best practices of docker when two different applications that spun up from two different docker compose files should be handled in terms of instances of databases and key:values stores like redis.

My example consists of two apache programs: Apache Airflow and Apache Superset. One is a scheduler and the other is a BI visualization tool.

I have docker compose for superset:

```
x-superset-image: &superset-image superset
x-superset-depends-on: &superset-depends-on
  - db
  - redis
x-superset-volumes:
  &superset-volumes # /app/pythonpath_docker will be appended to the PYTHONPATH in the final container
  - ./docker:/app/docker
  - superset_home:/app/superset_home

version: "3.7"
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:7.0.11-alpine
    container_name: superset_cache
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - redis:/data

  db:
    env_file: docker/.env-non-dev
    image: postgres-v15:latest
    container_name: superset_db
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - db_home:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./docker/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

  superset:
    env_file: docker/.env-non-dev
    image: *superset-image
    container_name: superset_app
    command: ["/app/docker/docker-bootstrap.sh", "app-gunicorn"]
    user: "root"
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8088:8088
    depends_on: *superset-depends-on
    volumes: *superset-volumes


volumes:
  superset_home:
    external: false
  db_home:
    external: false
  redis:
    external: false
```

And docker compose for airflow:

```
version: '3.8'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
    redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    db:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  db:
    image: postgres-v15:latest
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 5s
    restart: always

  redis:
    image: redis:7.0.11-alpine
    expose:
      - 6379

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
```

The point here is that both compose files use common images, that is redis and postgres. I would like to know what is a good design , to leave this as it is and have two instances of postgres and redis or try to make both application to use a single instance of redis and postgres ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the setup you've shown here, each Compose file is self-contained and isolated from each other.  One project doesn't have a hidden dependency on the other, or on some third Docker setup.  If the two projects use the same database tables or Redis keys, since there are separate stores they won't interfere with each other.

The setup you've shown here is a best practice in terms of container layout, even if it looks like you're wasting resources by having two separate databases.